# Changing content of an single input field after cloning form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an interface for my admins where they can add fields to a database. If they want to add several fields they can easily add a new line. This is done by cloning via JavaScript. Now there is one dropdown menu and based on the selection from the dropdown I want to write default values to the text-input fields for min[] and max[].

This works fine if I am having just one line. But if I clone it several times and make a selection (e. g. I am selecting the option "relative_number") in just one line (e. g.) the min and max fields are updated in every line. What can I do so that when the drop down is selected in a certain line only the min and max values in the same line are updated?

[image]
Here is my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="entities_wrap">   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
       <label>Name</label>
           <input type="text" name="entity_name[]" value="" style="width: 275px;" class="form-control" id="entity_name[]" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
       <label>Field Name</label>
           <input type="text" name="entity_field_name[]" value="" style="width: 275px;" class="form-control" id="entity_field_name[]" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>Category</label>
            <select id="entity_field_type[]" name="entity_field_type[]" class="form-select">                                                                 <option value=""></option>                                                 <option value="absolute_number">absolute_number</option>                                                            <option value="relative_number">relative_number</option>                                                    <option value="likert_5">likert_5</option>                                                      <option value="likert_7">likert_7</option>                                                              <option value="string">string</option>                                                       </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-1 minValue">
             <label>Min</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control min" id="min[]" name="min[]" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <label>Max</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control max" id="max[]" name="max[]" value=""/>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="vertical-align: middle;">
         <label>&nbsp;</label>
         <div style="margin: 0px 10px;">
             <i class="fas fa-trash remove-item"></i></span>
         </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-1" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <div style="margin: 0px 10px;">
        <i class="fas fa-plus add-plus"></i> <span class="plus">Add Line</span>
        </div>
    </div>
      </div><br>
    </div>
 </div>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
            
$(".add-plus").click(function(){   
$(".entities_wrap:last").clone(true).appendTo(".wrapper");
});

$(".plus").click(function(){   
$(".entities_wrap:last").clone(true).appendTo(".wrapper");
});

$(".remove-item").click(function () {           
$(this).closest(".entities_wrap").remove();
});
            
});

$('select[id^="entity_field_type"]').on('change', function()
{
    var sel_cat = this.value;

    if(sel_cat == 'relative_number')
    {
        $('input[id^="min"]').val("0");
        $('input[id^="max"]').val("100");
    }
    if(sel_cat == 'absolute_number')
    {
        $('input[id^="min"]').val("0");
        $('input[id^="max"]').val("infinite");
    }
    // For the other options the code should work alike

 });
</script>
```

Tried already different ways to solve it via DOM, identifying parent nodes, siblings and so on but I don't get it working.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Well, `id` should be unique. If you're cloning the elements, increment the id so they are unique then it's easy to assign a value to specific id selectors `#min1` `#max1`. Another "trick" might be to assign a class to the newly-cloned items, then it's easy to find and update; finally remove the class after you've assigned the vales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you should definitely look at dynamically modifying the names and id's of your cloned inputs, the issue you are having relates to your selectors for `min` and `max`

In the case of your javascript

```
  $('input[id^="min"]').val("0");
  $('input[id^="max"]').val("100");
```

You are selecting all `min` and `max` on the page.
You *need* to find the *related* `min` and `max`, which means finding the closet `.row` to the select-box and then finding the child min/max

```
  var $row = $(this).closest("div.row");
  $row.find('input[id^="min"]').val("0");
  $row.find('input[id^="max"]').val("100");
```

[jQuery closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[jQuery find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Here is a functioning snippet example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".add-plus").click(function() {
    $(".entities_wrap:last").clone(true).appendTo(".wrapper");
  });

  $(".plus").click(function() {
    $(".entities_wrap:last").clone(true).appendTo(".wrapper");
  });

  $(".remove-item").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".entities_wrap").remove();
  });

});

$('select[id^="entity_field_type"]').on('change', function() {
  var sel_cat = this.value;
  var $row = $(this).closest("div.row"); //find the parent row we are in.
  if (sel_cat == 'relative_number') {
    $row.find('input[id^="min"]').val("0"); //use that row to find the related min
    $row.find('input[id^="max"]').val("100"); //use that row to find the related max
  }
  if (sel_cat == 'absolute_number') {
    $row.find('input[id^="min"]').val("0");
    $row.find('input[id^="max"]').val("infinite");
  }
  // For the other options the code should work alike

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="entities_wrap">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="entity_name[]" value="" style="width: 275px;" class="form-control" id="entity_name[]" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Field Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="entity_field_name[]" value="" style="width: 275px;" class="form-control" id="entity_field_name[]" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Category</label>
        <select id="entity_field_type[]" name="entity_field_type[]" class="form-select">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="absolute_number">absolute_number</option>
          <option value="relative_number">relative_number</option>
          <option value="likert_5">likert_5</option>
          <option value="likert_7">likert_7</option>
          <option value="string">string</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 minValue">
        <label>Min</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control min" id="min[]" name="min[]" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <label>Max</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control max" id="max[]" name="max[]" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <div style="margin: 0px 10px;">
          <i class="fas fa-trash remove-item"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <div style="margin: 0px 10px;">
          <i class="fas fa-plus add-plus"></i> <span class="plus">Add Line</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and kudos to Steve0! Easy solution and it works perfect!